# Importing text files with the filename included

Tags: ms-access, vba

I initially wanted to setup a textbox where users can type in a date of a text file and click import(I created the from and did some coding but failed and could not find s
upport for my issue). This would grab the text file and import it to a table.

These are weekly reports that would need to be imported into the table.
My best alternative through research and trail and error came out to a macro
Here is my code:

```
Function InsertCMS_Reports_2ndSave()
    'DoCmd.DeleteObject Table, "CCS_Reports_2ndSave"
    DoCmd.TransferText acImportFixed, "CCS_Reports_Import", _
    "CCS_Reports_Import", "C:\Users\ABCDEF2\Desktop\January CCS reports for Centene\ABC_COMPRPT_1701011028174_h0062.txt"
End Function
```

What  it does is when I launch the database, it automatically executes the macro because I built a macro and assigned the name, autoexec to it. What the macro does is add the text file data into the table based off the import spec I made. Surprisingly, it imports it perfectly but there are more things I am trying to do it. I will probably be required to create multiple threads/questions so for now, I will include just one question here.

1)  When importing these files, how can I add the name of the file to the last column and have the file name display for every row as well.

So at this point, I would have to constantly disable the macro once its opened, or change the filename to the new weekly file, save it, close it and re-open it. It is not the most efficient but it seems like it might work.

Comment: If I were to just run a UPDATE query to update the fields, where do I exactly execute that query?

Comment: I ended up using an update query and that solved my problem. If anyone knows a more efficient please let me know.

Comment: Anybody know how I could execute this, without having to always launch the DB since its the macro? Could I just have it run when I choose too?

Comment: in VBA: ```Docmd.OpenQuery "QueryName"``` or ```Docmd.RunSql "Query SQL"```

Answer (score 0):

This should do just what you want.  I put some helpful comments in there too.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

        Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
        Dim strTable As String
        Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

        ' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
        ' has field names
        blnHasFieldNames = False

        ' Replace C:\Documents\ with the real path to the folder that
        ' contains the EXCEL files
        strPath = "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\test\"

        ' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which
        ' the data are to be imported
        strTable = "tablename"

        strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.txt")
        Do While Len(strFile) > 0
              strPathFile = strPath & strFile
              DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , strTable, strPathFile, True

              On Error Resume Next
              CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE tablename ADD FileName CHAR(25)"

              CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tablename SET FileName = '" & _
              strFile & "' WHERE FileName IS NULL", dbFailOnError

        strFile = Dir()
        Loop

End Sub
```

As for the loading.  When do you get the files?  I would think files would come in once per day.  Is that realistic?  You can run the Windows TaskScheduler, based on the tutorial below.

http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-create-task-basic-task-wizard

Finally, I would do this as an overnight job if I was you.

```
    Create an AutoExec macro

    If you have already created a macro that contains the actions that you want to occur when the database starts, just rename the macro AutoExec, and it will run the next time that you open the database. Otherwise, follow these steps to create a macro:

        On the Create tab, in the Other group, click Macro. If this command is unavailable, click the arrow beneath either the Module or the Class Module button, and then click Macro.

        In the Macro Builder, in the first empty Action cell, select the action that you want to perform. If applicable, under Action Arguments, type the appropriate values in

 the argument boxes.

    If you cannot find the action you want, on the Design tab, in the Show/Hide group, make sure Show All Actions is selected. This expands the list of actions that you can use, but the list will include some actions that will only run if the database is granted trusted status. For more information, see the articles Decide whether to trust a database or How database objects behave when trusted and untrusted.

    Repeat step 2 for each additional action you want to occur.

    Click Save, and in the Save As dialog box, type AutoExec.

    Click OK and then close the Macro Builder. The new macro will run the next time that you open the database.
```